# Updated successfully but doesnt update the table in my database it updates supplier table but the other table which is the supplier_location do not

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
    Dim query As String = "Update supplier_location set House_Num = @House_num,Province = @Province,City = @City,Barangay = @Barangay
    where location_id = @locationID "
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locationID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txtSearch.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@House_num", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txtHouseNumber.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Province", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtProvince.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCity.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Barangay", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBarangay.Text
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    query = "UPDATE supplier 
    set Supplier_id = @supplier_id,First_Name = @supplier_fname, Middle_Name = @supplier_mname, 
    Last_name = @supplier_lname where supplier_id = @searchID"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplier_id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txtSupplierID.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplier_fname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFirstName.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplier_mname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtMiddleName.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplier_lname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLastName.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txtSearch.Text
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    clearAllTextBox()
    MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfuly", "Eagle Clothing", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    showData()
```

I am expecting both tables to update but turns out that supplier table is only table that is updated and supplier_location is still the same

Comment: Based on that code, you are potentially changing the `supplier_id` of that record in the `supplier` table. Is that really want you want to do? If you don't want to change that column then why have you included it in the `SET` cause of the `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: Please note that the adding syntax is wrong: it should be more like `cmd.Parameters.Add("@locationID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(txtSearch.Text)`. Notice that the command is `Add`, and the type of the value to be assigned to the parameter has been converted into to the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

The Jet and ACE OLE DB providers, used for Access databases and various other data sources, do not support named parameters. They only support positional parameters. You can and should use names to make your code more readable but they are ignored by the database engine.

In your code, the difference between the two commands is that, for the second one, you are adding the parameters in the same order as they appear in the SQL code while, for the first, you are adding them in a different order. In the first command, you have this filter:

```sql
where location_id = @locationID
```

but that is the fifth parameter in the SQL code. In your VB code, this is the fifth parameter you add to the command:

```vb
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Barangay", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBarangay.Text
```

There is no record in the database with a `location_id` that matches so no record is updated. You need to add the parameters to the command in the same order as they appear in the SQL code, i.e.:

```vb
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@House_num", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txtHouseNumber.Text
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Province", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtProvince.Text
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCity.Text
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Barangay", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBarangay.Text
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locationID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txtSearch.Text
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is in sql update statement

Change your UPDATE query to...

query = "UPDATE supplier
set First_Name = @supplier_fname, Middle_Name = @supplier_mname,
Last_name = @supplier_lname where supplier_id = @searchID"

**Edit:**
After reading what jmcilhinney had written I saw that it was the wrong table which I addressed. None the less you DON'T want to update something if its not changed, and even more so if its a keyindex!

The best option would be to break those two sql update actions up into two functions and include a Try, Catch, Finally block in each function.

And only call the second function if the first function suceeded and returned without any errors.

Ideally you would wrap each sql action in a try catch and catch any errors before they crash the program or halt compilation because of unhandled errors.

Here is the link for the Try, Catch Finally documentation too.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement

And some psuedo code:

```
Sub MainCourse()
    '
    dim errorinfo as string
    If UpdateSupplierLocation(LocationIdValue, HouseNumValue, ProvinceValue, CityValue, BarangayValue, errorinfo) = True then
        If UpdateSupplier(SearchIdValue, FName, MName, LName, errorinfo) = True then
            clearAllTextBox()
            MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfuly", "Eagle Clothing", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            showData()
        Else
            'update supplier error occurred - handle it
        End If
    Else
        'update location error occurred handle it
    End if
End Sub


Function UpdateSupplierLocation(byval LocationIdValue as integer, byval HouseNumValue as integer, byval ProvinceValue as string, byval CityValue as string, byval BarangayValue as string, byref ErrInfo as string) as boolean
    'validate data
    if LocationIdValue > 0 then
        'update supplier location
        Try
            'execute nonquery here
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            UpdateSupplierLocation = true
        Catch Ex as exeption
            ErrInfo = ex.message
            UpdateSupplierLocation = false
        End Try
        con.Close()
    Else
        ErrInfo = "Invalid locationid"
        UpdateSupplierLocation = false
    End if
end function


Function UpdateSupplier(byval SearchIdValue as integer, byval FName as string, byval MName as string, byval LName as string, byref ErrInfo as string) as boolean
    'validate
    If SearchIdValue > 0 then
        'update supplier 
        'prepare your query and parameters here
        Try 
            'try to execute nonquery here
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            UpdateSupplier = true
        Catch Ex as exeption
            ErrInfo = ex.message
            UpdateSupplier = false
        End Try
        con.Close()
    else
        ErrInfo = "Invalid supplierid"
        UpdateSupplier = false
    end if
end function
```

Comment: The question says that the `supplier` table is updated successfully so that command is working. It is the other command that isn't working because the `supplier_location` table is not updated.

Comment: I think you're right about that change being a good idea - the `supplier_id` should not be changing and if it's not changing then it shouldn't be set - but it doesn't actually address the question that was actually asked.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, yes that was my thought too, I read it on the bus to work, but will re-read it again when I have more time...

Comment: With regards to only calling the second function if the first succeeds, you can just put both updates together and wrap them in a transaction. They will then either both succeed or both fail. They should be done together because there should be a single connection, opened once and then closed after both updates.